# Proteus custom library backup

Tags: proteus

I have just created a whole load of new component definition and saved under USERDVC in a library. Where is this located so I can back it up?

Comment: Most operating systems have a system or drive wide search command allowing you to find file names or file content that matches certain search criteria. Use that to find where the files are stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the application menu select `Library -> Library manager`

[image]

In the dialog that opens select the library you want (USERDVC in this case) and click the info button to see the path it resides in.

[image]

To backup the library just backup the `LibraryName.LIB` and `LibraryName.IDX` files.